# History of complex numbers

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, math-history

I'm interested in the history of complex numbers - their origin and their subsequent development.

I'd be very interested if anyone can provide references for finding out more about this topic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_complex_numbers#History

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *An Imaginary Tale: The Story of $i$* by Paul Nahin is very nice, and has a fair amount of historical material.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.math.uri.edu/~merino/spring06/mth562/ShortHistoryComplexNumbers2006.pdf) is a brief 5-page essay outlining the history of them as well.